# AutoMapper: How to map a relationship data as array

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have 3 tables.

**Company**

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Company 1 |
| 2 | Company 2 |

**Users**

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1d0ba340-7ff6-47a4-a9a4-46345a228e53 | User 1 |
| 229c4525-e12d-4a01-8eda-e611ca8b721c | User 2 |

**UserCompany**

| Id | UserId | CompanyId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0DCA3DBE-747F-489B-A85D-2BE7E1A03140 | 1d0ba340-7ff6-47a4-a9a4-46345a228e53 | 1 |
| 123C04DB-A62B-4B4A-AA5C-CE1E35540BB0 | 1d0ba340-7ff6-47a4-a9a4-46345a228e53 | 2 |
| 2306F3EA-173F-4F47-8C11-62C29A963C9F | 229c4525-e12d-4a01-8eda-e611ca8b721c | 2 |

I have a DTO which is meant to map the Company Table with the list of users assigned to each company. The DTO is as follows.

```
public record CompanyDto(
    int Id,
    string Name, 
    IEnumerable<string> UsersList);
```

In this DTO I need to list users' names against each company. How can I do this using AutoMapper?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the code for your entities look like this:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping profile for the automapper can look like this

```
public class CompanyProfile : Profile
{
    public CompanyProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Company, CompanyDto>()
            .ForMember(x => x.UsersList, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Users.Select(y => y.Name)));
    }
}
```

Notice that I ommited **Id** and **Name**, because AutoMapper can map them autamtically (same name and type).